# Перехват событий консоли

Tags: javascript, html, объекты, консоль

Всем привет,как мне перехватить события консоли вида info,log,warn,error вот таким способом

```
 function takeOverConsole(){
        var console = window.console;
        if (!console) return
        function intercept(method){
            var original = console[method];
            console[method] = function(){
                // do sneaky stuff
                if (original.apply){
                    // Do this for normal browsers
                    original.apply(console, arguments)
                }else{
                    // Do this for IE
                    var message = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).join(' ');
                    original(message)
                }
            }
        }
        var methods = ['log','info', 'warn', 'error'];
        for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
            intercept(methods[i])
    }
```

и передать эти события в метод `window.test.setLog(obj)`
а сам объект должен быть вида

```
obj = {
type:error
message:'сообщение',
type:warn
message:'сообщение'
и т.д
}
```

Comment: _вот таким способом_ который ты привел в вопросе

Comment: да,это пример,просто не пойму как правильно его использовать

Comment: как минимум эту функцию надо вызвать

Comment: вызвать то я ее вызову) в другом вопрос)

Comment: В чем в другом? :-)

Comment: как это все должно работать и выглядеть,с передачей объекта) У меня не очень получается,хочу что-то рабочее,чтобы разобраться))

Comment: вот тут `console[method] = function(){` ты создаешь свою функцию type в твоем объекте - это method, message - непонятно что, но у тебя есть все аргументы с которыми будет вызвана функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для IE не поддерживающего `Function.prototype.apply()` сообщение будет объединением аргументов в строку, для поддерживающих браузеров - псевдомассив аргументов "arguments".

```js
function takeOverConsole () {
  var console = window.console

  if (!console) return

  function intercept (method) {
    var original = console[method]

    console[method] = function () {
      var message
      // do sneaky stuff
      if (original.apply) {
        // Do this for normal browsers
        original.apply(console, arguments)
        
        message = arguments
      } else {
        // Do this for IE
        message = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).join(' ')

        original(message)
      }
      
      var obj = {
        type: method,
        message: message
      }
      
      // тут доступен obj
      alert(obj.type)
    }
  }
  var methods = ['log', 'info', 'warn', 'error']

  for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    intercept(methods[i])
  }
}

takeOverConsole();

window.console.log(123)
```